# Android studio/libGDX/admob cannot find dependecies()

Tags: java, libgdx, admob

So I've been searching around for days trying to figure out why I can't implement admob into my Android Studio project.

Things I've tried:
I have the google play services installed and latest Android SDKs

File->Project Structure->ads->ticking admob
--this will try to load in the dependencies, and always fails with 
(Error:Could not find method dependencies() for arguments [build_23ysmkvnpvbphbg3g4deijgq4$_run_closure6@4afc19b] on org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModel_Decorated@18b40be.)

I've tried deleting the .gradle folder, restarting AS and rebuilding with the same Error.

I've tried creating a new blank LibGDX project and importing that and directly getting the admob dependencies and still the same error message.

I'm honestly not sure what I'm overlooking here. 
If there's any info you feel I've left out, please let me know.

Comment: And to mention. I just tried adding the admob dependencies on a blank project that I didn't import from a libgdx project and that worked perfectly fine. That furthers my "what am I doing wrong"-ness.

Comment: please show your build.gradle of android module ?

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm coming from the Eclipse environment, and whenever I built a libgdx project, I've never had to go into the "advanced" settings. so messing around some more I went into the advanced settings and saw a checkbox for IDEA(generates intellij IDEA project files) which has seemed to work in getting rid of that error.